# UITableViewSeparator only shows when scrolling using VIPER architecture

Tags: ios, swift, viper-architecture

i've a weird situation where my `UITableViewSeparators` are only appearing when i scroll.
I created a very simple project with a `UITableView` listing a list of cars. Im using `VIPER` architecture.

[image: There is no UITableViewSeparator, only shows during scroll]

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ivangodfather/b3411f9af0ab78b38dd6) with relevant clases. 
[Here](https://schibsted.box.com/ViperArch) is the sample project.

Comment: I run your project on simulator and on real device. In both cases it's works correct

Comment: try it on simulator 6+ ?

Comment: Yes on 6 plus simulater there are no separators:(

Comment: due to resolution of your monitor and simulator you can't see lines. try on device.

Comment: @TejasArdeshna yes you are totally right, when i make the simulator bigger CMD+1/2/3) the lines appears. Thx

Comment: Im trying to use VIPER architecture with UITableViews. Where did you place the delegate methods?

Comment: Usually on the view calling the presenter